# string parsing in java for android application

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

How do I parse this string,

```
=w115113298015
```

so that I get only the first 13 characters after the equals sign.

and this string

```
 c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|=w11511329801500
```

so that I get the first 13 characters after the  last equals sign;

sometimes this string wont have the equals sign ,

```
 c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|w11511329801500
```

and I'll need the first 13 characters after the last | sign.

So I get the w115113298015 from both strings and compare them with each other.

I used this code to match the strings which were equal, but the strings I'm using now are different. Any input would be helpful.

```
String firstContents = intent.getStringExtra("first_contents")
String secondContents = intent.getStringExtra("second_contents")

if (firstContents.equals(secondContents)) { 
   rest of code here.
```

How do I add code to this to parse the string ?

Thanks

Comment: What did you tried your self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
    String s = "c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|w11511329801500";
    String string = null;
    if (s.contains("=")) {
        string = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
    } else {
        string = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("|") + 1);
    }
    if (string.length() >= 13) {
        string = string.substring(0, 13);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This splits the string on the `|` character and gets the last part. If the first character of the last part is `=`, it is removed. The resulting string is then trimmed to be of length 13.

```
    String input = "c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|=w11511329801500";
    String[] parts = input.split("\\|");
    String comparableLastPart = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (comparableLastPart.charAt(0) == '=') {
        comparableLastPart = comparableLastPart.substring(1);
    }

    if (comparableLastPart.length() > 13) {
        comparableLastPart = comparableLastPart.substring(0, 13);
    }

    System.out.println("comparableLastPart: " + comparableLastPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the following way.

1. Find the index of `=` using the [`indexOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method.
2. If its equal to `-1`, then `=` symbol is not present.

   a. Find the last index of `|` char using [`lastIndexOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) method.

   b. From this index, extract a substring from the actual string using [`substring(startIndex, endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method(from the last index of `|` to the next 13 characters).
3. If index of `=` is not equal to `-1`, then extract a substring from the actual string using [`substring(startIndex, endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method(from the index of `=` to the next 13 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this works like charm

```
public String parseString(String input) {

        if (input != null) {
            if (input.contains("=")) {
                String arr[] = input.split("=");
                return arr[arr.length - 1];
            } else {
                String arr[] = input.split("\\|");
                return arr[arr.length - 1];
            }
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
```

**How to use?**

```
System.out.println(parseString("=w11511329801500"));
        System.out.println(parseString("c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|=w11511329801500"));
        System.out.println(parseString("c5|208971|YAhj56|thoimn|10/8/79|T|w11511329801500"));
```